# FFMPEG (Java / Bramp) : Filter Scale has an unconnected output

Tags: java, spring-boot, ffmpeg, hls, bramp

Estoy intentando generar un archivo HLS a partir de un mp4 desde Java/Spring usando la librería [bramp/ffmpeg-cli-wrapper](https://github.com/bramp/ffmpeg-cli-wrapper), pero al hacerlo obtengo el error "Filter scale has an unconnected output".

He leído [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47328079/filter-has-an-unconnected-output) que debo:

- Encerrar los parámetros del filter_complex entre comillas
- Eliminar el parámetro -map
- Eliminar [output]
- Añadir espacios en blanco después de cada salto de línea.

He estado probando tanto esto como muchas otras cosas que he encontrado, pero no consigo que funcione, y como tampoco conozco ffmpeg porque llevo apenas unos días, pues tampoco sé qué más probar.

Este es mi código:

```
public File createHls(
            @RequestParam(required = false, name = "file") MultipartFile multipartFile
        ) throws Exception {
        
        
        //Esto me devuelve un file a partir del MultipartFile que le paso por parámetro
        File file = multipartToFile(multipartFile);
        
        //FFMPEG
        FFmpeg ffmpeg = new FFmpeg("C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe");
        FFprobe ffprobe = new FFprobe("C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffprobe.exe");
        
        String outputPath = env.getProperty("spring.servlet.multipart.location");
        
        
        //String complexFilter = "[0:v]copy[v0]; [1:v]scale=w=1280:h=720[v1]; [2:v]scale=w=640:h=360[v2];[v0][v1][v2]xstack=inputs=3:layout=0_0|0_h0|w0_0|w0_h0[v]', '-map', '[v]', '-c:v', 'libx265', '-crf', '12', '-preset', 'ultrafast', '-an', output]";
        //String complexFilter = "[0:v]split=3[v1][v2][v3]; [v1]copy[v1out]; [v2]scale=w=1280:h=720[v2out]; [v3]scale=w=640:h=360[v3out] -map [v1out] -c:v:0 libx264 -x264-params \"nal-hrd=cbr:force-cfr=1\" -b:v:0 5M -maxrate:v:0 5M -minrate:v:0 5M -bufsize:v:0 10M -preset slow -g 48 -sc_threshold 0 -keyint_min 48 -map [v2out] -c:v:1 libx264 -x264-params \"nal-hrd=cbr:force-cfr=1\" -b:v:0 3M -maxrate:v:0 3M -minrate:v:0 3M -bufsize:v:0 3M -preset slow -g 48 -sc_threshold 0 -keyint_min 48 -map [v3out] -c:v:2 libx264 -x264-params \"nal-hrd=cbr:force-cfr=1\" -b:v:0 1M -maxrate:v:0 1M -minrate:v:0 1M -bufsize:v:0 1M -preset slow -g 48 -sc_threshold 0 -keyint_min 48 -map a:0 -c:a:0 aac -b:a:0 96k -ac 2 -map a:0 -c:a:1 aac -b:a:1 96k -ac 2 -map a:0 -c:a:2 aac -b:a:2 48k -ac 2";
        String complexFilter = "[0:v]split=3[v1][v2][v3]; [v1]copy[v1out]; [v2]scale=w=1280:h=720[v2out]; [v3]scale=w=640:h=360[v3out]";
        
        FFmpegBuilder builder = new FFmpegBuilder()
                
                .setInput(file.getAbsolutePath())
                .setComplexFilter(complexFilter)
                .overrideOutputFiles(true)
                .addOutput(outputPath + "HLS_" + file.getName())
                
                .disableSubtitle()
                
                .setAudioCodec("copy")
                .setVideoCodec("copy")
                
                .setStrict(FFmpegBuilder.Strict.EXPERIMENTAL)
                .done();
        
        FFmpegExecutor executor = new FFmpegExecutor(ffmpeg, ffprobe);
        
        executor.createJob(builder).run();
        
        return new File(outputPath + "HLS_" + file.getName());
        
    }
```

Agradecería muchísimo cualquier tipo de ayuda o alternativa para lo que estoy haciendo.